# How can I effectively replace one or more characters

Tags: android, string, replace

I have a String separated by commas as follows

> 1,2,4,6,8,11,14,15,16,17,18

This string is generated upon user input. Suppose the user wants to remove any of the numbers, I have to rebuild the string without the specified number.

If the current string is:

> 1,2,4,6,8,11,14,15,16,17,18

User intents to remove `1`, the final string has to be:

> 2,4,6,8,11,14,15,16,17,18

I tried to achieve this using the following code:

```
 //String num will be the number to be removed
 old = tv.getText().toString(); //old string
 newString = old.replace(num+",",""); //will be the new string
```

This might be working sometimes but it is sure that it won't work for the above example I have shown, if I try to remove the `1`, it also removes the last part of `11`, because there also exists `1`.

Comment: As you have noticed, this is difficult with a simple character replacement. Instead, separate the individual numbers and work on that level. Then combine the numbers again to the string form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can use this. Its the most simplest approach i can think of:

```
//String num will be the number to be removed
 old=","+tv.getText().toString()+",";//old string commas added to remove trailing entries
 newString=old.replace(","+num+",",",");// will be the new string
 newString=newString.substring(1,newString.length()-1); // removing the extra commas added
```

This would work for what you want to do. I have added a comma at the start and end of your string so that you can also remove the first and last entries too.

Comment: Probably the most simplest idea!!! I think this one is better approach than splitting the string into array an then searching inside the array !! thanks for the idea

Comment: This logic is also having some problems :) so I separated the numbers by spaces before them and tried to replace it.. its working perfectly

Comment: @Shan can you tell me about the problem you are having?

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7 oops, I cant recall the exact problem, But i remember :when i tried to remove some character from the list, it just replaces it and final string will be rebuild with error! Sorry i cant rebuid the exact error now.

Comment: @Shan i'll retest the code and correct it incase i find a problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the string first and check for the number where you append those value that is not equivalent to the number that will get deleted;

**sample:**

```
 String formated = "1,2,4,6,8,11,14,15,16,17,18";
    String []s = formated.split(",");
    StringBuilder newS = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s2 : s)
    {
        if(!s2.equals("1"))
            newS.append(s2 + ",");
    }
    if(newS.length() >= 1)
        newS.deleteCharAt(newS.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(newS);
```

**result:**

```
2,4,6,8,11,14,15,16,17,18
```

Comment: If you wanted to remove "18" (the last item in the string), your solution would generate a string with a trailing comma.

Comment: @selbie nice catch, editted to delete the last comma

Comment: Now you have another minor bug. If the original string contained only a single item, and that item gets removed, you'll invoke deleteCharAt(-1). I assume that throws an exception...

Comment: @selbie ya, but I thought that users wont have lessthan 1 input oh well editted again.

Comment: Rule #1 - assume all input from outside yoru code are malicious attempts to crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
static public String removeItemFromCommaDelimitedString(String str, String item)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;

    String [] splits = str.split(",");

    for (String s : splits)
    {
        if (item.equals(s) == false)
        {
            if (count != 0)
            {
                builder.append(',');
            }
            builder.append(s);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     String old = "1,2,4,6,8,11,14,15,16,17,18";
     int num = 11;
     String toRemove = "," + num + "," ;
     String oldString = "," + old + ",";
     int index = oldString.indexOf(toRemove);
     System.out.println(index);
     String newString = null;
     if(index > old.length() - toRemove.length() + 1){
        newString = old.substring(0, index - 1);
     }else{
         newString = old.substring(0, index) + old.substring(index + toRemove.length()    -1 , old.length());
     }
     System.out.println(newString);
```